# Scala: Incorrect warning "match may not be exhaustive"

Tags: scala

Consider the following snippet:

```
sealed abstract class Bar
object B1 extends Bar
object B2 extends Bar
object B3 extends Bar
case class A(bar:Bar)

def foo(a:A) = a match {
    case A(bar@(B1|B2)) =>
        bar match { // gives warning here
            case B1 => 
            case B2 => 
        } 
    case _ =>
}
```

In the above, I am ensuring that the first case matches only when `A` is of type `A(B1)` or `A(B2)` (at least that's what I think it means). However, I am getting the following error:

```
warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: B3
       bar match {
       ^
```

Can anyone elaborate why the warning is coming?

EDIT: After the answers, it seems that the compiler types `bar` as `Bar` without remembering that it is matched. It is definitely not a bug. The compilier is smart enough to not give a warning in the following:

```
sealed abstract class Bar
object B1 extends Bar
object B2 extends Bar
object B3 extends Bar
case class A(bar:Bar)

def foo(a:A) = a match {
    case A(B1|B2) =>
        a match { // no warning
            case A(B1) => 
            case A(B2) => 
        } 
    case _ =>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose it's because the type given to `bar` is the supertype (`bar` could be a `B1` or `B2` and the only common type is `Bar`), so theoretically it could still be a `B3` and the compiler is not smart enough for this:

```
def foo(a:A) = a match {
  case A(bar@(B1|B2)) =>
    bar match { // bar here has a Bar type
        case B1 => 
        case B2 => 
    } 
  case _ =>
}
```

Anyway, what would be the point here of having a nested match when you could have a flat match with the same result?

Comment: Its actually a more complex case, with several subtypes of `Bar`. If needed, I can give a better example.

Comment: If you want to keep this match structure you need a more refined hierarchy implementation, for example `B1` and `B2` could be subtypes of `Bar` and of `Bar1And2` and then have a better param match, although I'm not sure you want to have this, doesn't look too nice to me.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the compiler. The match works nicely in other cases.

Comment: @Jus12 I'd just call it a limitation, not a proper bug. In this case, the compiler can not see that the match is exhaustive from the type of `bar` alone,i.e. from `A`, it needs information about its actual value. It's not very different from `if (x == 0) { x match { case 0 => ... } }` which is exhaustive, but requires a very smart compiler to spot that.

Comment: @chi Your example is somewhat different because in my case, we have a sealed class with a limited number of sub-types. So the compiler _should_ be able to figure this out. I've seen the compiler do lots of other stuff that seems like magic and this one seems trivial.

Comment: @Jus12 you have a sealed trait with 3 subclasses, you match on 2 of those and the compiler infers the super type, on a next match the compiler cannot know that your logic excludes one type, it's definitely not a bug.

Comment: Not a bug but a possible enhancement.